# Concatenar en el payload Python-Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Estoy realizando un POST en una API, estoy utilizando Python-Requests para esto, este código me lo generó desde Postman, y funciona perfectamente, el tema está en que quiero concatenar una variable en el payload

```
cod = "15151"
```

Entonces la variable `cod` quiero concatenarla en `\"comuna\": \"15151\"` entonces cambiar el 15151 por `cod`

```
payload="{\r\n    \"metaData\": {\r\n        \"namespace\": \"cl.sii.sdi.lob.bbrr.mapas.data.api.interfaces.MapasFacadeService/getPredioNacional\",\r\n        \"conversationId\": \"UNAUTHENTICATED-CALL186.11.79.43\",\r\n        \"transactionId\": \"795fd53b-478a-e7e6-0fa4-84e64666605e\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"data\": {\r\n        \"predio\": {\r\n            \"comuna\": \"15151\",\r\n            \"manzana\": \"08261\",\r\n            \"predio\": \"00014\"\r\n        },\r\n        \"servicios\": [\r\n            {\r\n                \"comuna\": 15151,\r\n                \"layer\": \"sii:BR_CART_AH_MUESTRAS\",\r\n                \"style\": \"AH_MUESTRA\",\r\n                \"eac\": 11,\r\n                \"eacano\": 2018\r\n            }\r\n        ]\r\n    }\r\n}\r\n"
```

Comment: La biblioteca requests permite agregar un argumento json para el método POST que transforma un diccionario o una lista de listas en su representación en JSON. En tu ejemplo pareciera que es lo que tratas de hacer con tu cadena que al final de cuenta  representa un JSON, intenta especificar un poco más tu problema, no se entiende que es realmente lo que buscas obtener al final.

Answer (score 0):

Debes de usar la función replace()

Así quedaría:

```
cod = "15151"
payload = "\"comuna\": \"15151\""
payload.replace("15151",cod)
```

Lo que hace esto es que va remplazar el valor de 15151 por el valor que tú le asignes a tu variable cod.

El primer parámetro que se le introduce a replace, es un objeto tipo str al cual quieras hacerle la modificación, y el segundo parámetro es el que se va sustituir en el pedazo de str que quieras.

Otro ejemplo sería:

```
payload = "hola mundo"
cod = "marte"
payload.replace("mundo",cod)
```

Donde la salida de este código sería: "hola marte", se sustituyeron las palabras.